# Jinja function continuously update

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

From what it seems like, after calling a Jinja function, the return value is "set in stone" and cannot be changed, however, I need a way to call a Jinja function and get its current return value continuously. Currently I have the following code:

app.py [SNIPPET]

```
def statusupdate():
    return status

app.jinja_env.globals.update(statusupdate=statusupdate)
```

index.html [SNIPPET]

```
<script>
function stat(){
    if ("{{ statusupdate() }}" == "Done"){
        clearInterval(id)
        window.location.href = '/results'
    } else {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "{{ statusupdate() }}"
    }
}
id = setInterval(stat, 0)
</script>
```

Throughout `app.py`, the `status` variable is changing quite a bit. However, the page and specifically the element with id "status" is frozen at the initial value and is never updated. Is there a way to allow this to update?

Answer (score -1):

I use something like this:

```py
def func_to_fetch_from_db(variable):
    ...

@app.context_processor
    def inject_global_vars():

        base_context = {
            'status': func_to_fetch_from_db('status'),
        }

        return base_context
```

Putting in db is best for me. The demo can be seen in use in the [shopyo](https://github.com/Abdur-rahmaanJ/shopyo/blob/dev/shopyo/app.py) app.